# Standard errors in GAMLSS vs LMER

Tags: lme4-nlme, gamlss

Why do the standard errors for `gamlss` are much lower than the standard errors from `lmer`?

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(gamlss)

fit <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
summary(fit)
# Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
# Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
#    Data: sleepstudy
# 
# REML criterion at convergence: 1786.5
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -3.2257 -0.5529  0.0109  0.5188  4.2506 
# 
# Random effects:
#  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  Subject  (Intercept) 1378.2   37.12   
#  Residual              960.5   30.99   
# Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18
# 
# Fixed effects:
#             Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 251.4051     9.7467  22.8102   25.79   <2e-16 ***
# Days         10.4673     0.8042 161.0000   13.02   <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#      (Intr)
# Days -0.371

fit <- gamlss(Reaction ~ Days + re(random = ~ 1|Subject), 
              data = sleepstudy, 
              family = "NO")
summary(fit)
# ******************************************************************
#   Family:  c("NO", "Normal") 
# 
# Call:  gamlss(formula = Reaction ~ Days + re(random = ~1 |  
#                                                Subject), family = "NO", data = sleepstudy, opt = "optim") 
# 
# Fitting method: RS() 
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Mu link function:  identity
# Mu Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 251.4051     4.0759   61.68   <2e-16 ***
#   Days         10.4673     0.7635   13.71   <2e-16 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Sigma link function:  log
# Sigma Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   3.3817     0.0527   64.16   <2e-16 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#   NOTE: Additive smoothing terms exist in the formulas: 
#   i) Std. Error for smoothers are for the linear effect only. 
# ii) Std. Error for the linear terms maybe are not accurate. 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#   No. of observations in the fit:  180 
# Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  18.76598
# Residual Deg. of Freedom:  161.234 
# at cycle:  2 
# 
# Global Deviance:     1728.238 
# AIC:     1765.77 
# SBC:     1825.689 
# ******************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard errors of the `gamlss` are conditioned on the values of the random component. The `lmer` standard errors integrate out the random component. As stated in Section 5.2 "Functions to obtain standard errors" of [Flexible Regression and Smoothing:  Using  GAMLSS  in R](https://www.gamlss.com/the-books/)

> When smoothing terms are fitted, `gen.likelihood()` considers them as fixed at their fitted values, so the Hessian in this case does not take into account the variability in the fitting of the smoothers.

The `gen.likelihood()`-function is used to make the `vcov` matrix from where the standard errors originate. In `gamlss` random effects are carefully constructed as a special type of smoothing. Hence, random effects are kept at their fixed value and which makes the standard errors for `gamlss` small.

In far most use cases, one should use the `lmer`-standard errors.

Comment: Did you mean that the standard errors for gamlss are underestimated instead of inflated since they do not take into account the variability fitting of the smoothers?

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, thank you! I have edited the post